# What does `|>` mean in TICKscript

Tags: influxdb

Trying to write my fist TICKscript to work out when two sensor values cross: if the outside temperature has changed from lower to higher than the inside temperature then I need to close the windows (and conversely).

Using the query builder in `InfluxDB` I'm getting this for the meadian of the temperature values inside the house over the last 15 minutes:

```
from(bucket: "zigbee")
  |> range(start: -15m, stop: now())
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["room"] == "Kitchen" or r["room"] == "DiningRoom" or r["room"] == "Bed3" or r["room"] == "Bed1")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "temperature")
  |> group(columns: ["_measurement"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 15m, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name:"inside")
```

The syntax `|>` appears to undocumented -- can you provide a reference?

Replacing `|>` with `|` breaks it.

It seems that `group` and `aggregateWindow` do not commute?
Presumably because `aggregateWindow` is forced to choose a single representative `_time` value for each window?

I think the plan is to

- assign this to a stream,
- copy and edit to creata a second stream `shift`ed by 15 minutes,
- create a second pair of streams for the outside temperature.
- join all four streams and caluclate a value indicating whether the inside and outside temperatures have crossed over.

Unless you have a better idea?
(Right now it's looking easier to import the data into SQL.)

Comment: https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.6/tick/syntax/#variables-and-literals#operators does not show this operator, this look like a pipe operator, maybe fsharp or something

Comment: You're right @kigiri; it's _not_ `TICKscript`.

Answer (score 1):

Check InfluxDB Flux language documentation for `|>`:

[InfluxDB Pipe-forward operator](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/get-started/syntax-basics/#pipe-forward-operator)

According to your flux syntax query:

```
from(bucket: "zigbee")
  |> range(start: -15m, stop: now())
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["room"] == "Kitchen" or r["room"] == "DiningRoom" or r["room"] == "Bed3" or r["room"] == "Bed1")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "temperature")
  |> group(columns: ["_measurement"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 15m, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name:"inside")
```

1. You are taking data from bucket "zigbee"
2. Data from source are passed to range filter function with pipe-forward `|>` operator
3. Results from range filter data are passed to next filter function with another pipe-forward operator
4. Etc.

So all data flows as a result from one function to another.

You can group by but in your case columns are `"room"` key values if I understand your intentions correctly, so try:

```
  |> group(columns: ["room"])
```

There is a difference between key values and measurement names - you should check InfluxDB documentation for understatnding data structure.

[Flux data model documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/get-started/data-model/)

Answer (score 0):

I'ts *not* `TICKscript`, it's something do to with InfluxDB that might be called `flux`.

```
mean = from(bucket: "zigbee")
  |> range(start: -5d, stop: now())
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["room"] == "Outside")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "temperature")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 30m, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)

shift =  mean
  |> timeShift(duration: -3h)

j = join(tables: {mean: mean, shift: shift}, on: ["_time"])
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with diff: float(v: r._value_mean) - float( v: r._value_shift) }))
// yield contains 1 table with the required columns, but the UI doesn't understand it.

// The UI requires 1 table for each series.
j |> map(fn: (r) => ({_time: r._time, _value: r._value_mean})) |> yield(name: "mean")
j |> map(fn: (r) => ({_time: r._time, _value: r._value_shift})) |> yield(name: "shift")
j |> map(fn: (r) => ({_time: r._time, _value: r.diff})) |> yield(name: "diff")
```

Answer (score -2):

The `|>` in TickScript "Declares a chaining method call which creates an instance of a new node and chains it to the node above it." as said in the official documentation

Comment: Reference? Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.6/tick/syntax/ which applies that description to `|` and does not mention `|>`.